# check Health for all APIs in the application and provide HTTP status code in the response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In my application there are 10 API's( rest controllers). I want to create a health check using spring boot actuator in order to have a detailed check for all the API's( including all rest controller). Currently, I am easily able to show the single API(Rest Controller) health by writing the customHealthIndicator class and override the health() method.
So is there any way to create a single customeHealthIndicator class and test all API's are UP or Down or for each API's(RestContorller) create the separate customeHealthIndicator class.

```
@Component
public class AlarmLogHealthIndicator
    implements HealthIndicator {

 @Autowired
  private AlarmLogService alarmLogService;



  private final String message_key = "v2/alarms/cumulativeDetails";


  @Override
  public Health health() {
    if (!isRunningServiceA()) {
      return Health.down().withDetail(message_key, "DOWN").build();
    }
    return Health.up().withDetail(message_key, "UP").build();
  }
  private Boolean isRunningServiceA() {
    Boolean isRunning = true;
   
    // Logic to check API is UP or DOWN

      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      HttpEntity<ToolModuleRequestDTO> entity = new HttpEntity<>(getRqstData(), headers);

      ResponseEntity<List<CumulativeDetailsDTO>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
             ("http://localhost:7072/v2/alarms/cumulativeDetails"),
              HttpMethod.POST, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CumulativeDetailsDTO>>() {} );


      if (responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue() ==500) {
          isRunning = false;
      } 
//           
    return isRunning;
  }
    private ToolModuleRequestDTO getRqstData(){
       ToolModuleRequestDTO toolModuleRequestDTO = new ToolModuleRequestDTO();
        
        LocalDate  startTime = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate  endTime = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        List   severity = new ArrayList<>();
        severity.add("Error");
        severity.add("Fatal");
        severity.add("Critical");
        String  exclude1 = "WAC";
        Map<String, String>  mapValue = new HashMap<>();
        mapValue.put(toolId, "9c9b8482-3ad6-4c2d-99e1-de2cda68a2d7");
      
               
        DateTimeFormatter formatterStart = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.SqlConstants.DATE_FORMAT_START);
        DateTimeFormatter formatterEnd = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(Constants.SqlConstants.DATE_FORMAT_END);
        String startTimeStr = formatterStart.format(startTime);
        String endTimeStr = formatterEnd.format(endTime);
//      startTimeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf(startTimeStr);
//      endTimeStamp = Timestamp.valueOf(endTimeStr);
        toolModuleRequestDTO.setStartDate(LocalDate.parse("2022-04-01"));
        toolModuleRequestDTO.setEndDate(LocalDate.parse("2022-04-30"));
        toolModuleRequestDTO.setSeverity("Critical,Error,Fatal");
        return toolModuleRequestDTO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to create a separate custom indicator class for each API.

Comment: He is asking general solution for the common problem, I think the answer needs to be updated for more precise answer. The problem is to implement health check for each API:
1. Which problem he wants to resolve?
2. How to give general solution that could be applied for other languages?
3. Which resource is more appropriate and informative that you can prove your statement?